# authorize an app that uses gmail api deploy using jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, deployment, google-api, google-oauth

I developed a java application that read a gmail inbox folder and proccess the retrieved messages.
I'm using gmail api with Oauth authorization to access this email.
The problem is that I need to use jenkins to deploy this app and at the first time you need to access a browser link to give access to gmail api. any idea how can I solve it?
I tried to send stored credential, but I always receive this  message in jenkins console:

Please open the following address in your browser:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8888/Callback&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive

Need a solution to deploy this app, there is another authorization type?

I've tried to copy stored credential with my project but it ask for open web browser again.
I authorized it in my local machine and copy credential to server.

it's a spring boot app My code is:

```
    public  Credential authorize(NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {
    // Load client secrets.
    InputStream in
            = PropriedadeService.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("client_secrets.json");
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets
            = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

    // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow
            = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                    HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
            .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
            .setAccessType("offline")
            .build();
    Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
            flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
    System.out.println(
            "Credentials saved to " + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());
    return credential;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.  Is this a web app or an installed app are you hosting it on a web server?

Comment: edited, code sent, its a web, springboot app, thanks